# Scala object as literal

Tags: scala, literals

I have an object which is a collection of case classes. This is what it looks like printed.

```
Sentence(List(),List(Word(Anarchism,Anarchism,NNP,I-NP,O,N), Word(.,.,.,O,O,.)))
```

is it possible to produce the scala literal that produces this object? The actual example is more complex, and also includes a bunch of characters that need to be escaped. The expected output would be similar to

```
Sentence(Seq(), Seq(Word("Anarchism", "Anarchism", "NNP", "I-NP", "O", "N"), Word(".", ".", ".", "O", "O", ".")))
```

Comment: produce as what... a String? An AST fragment?

Comment: @0__ a string. added.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
def scalaCodeForObject(x: Any): String = x match {
  // handle primitives
  case s: String =>
    // trim is used to make the strings clearer
    val escaped = s.replaceAll("""\""", """\\""").replaceAll(""" " """.trim, """ \" """.trim)
    s""" "$escaped" """.trim
  case i: Int => i.toString
  ...
  // all case classes are Products
  case p: Product =>
    val className = x.getClass.getSimpleName
    val fields = p.productIterator
    fields.map(scalaCodeForObject _).mkString(", ", className + "(", ")")
  // handle other cases you need, e.g. lists, other seqs, maps, etc.
}
```

Comment: People ask for this often, so it should have a place next to `ScalaRunTime.stringOf` and a REPL option to use it.

Comment: For products, I would use `productPrefix` instead of `getClass.getSimpleName`. In SuperCollider, this procedure is called `.asCompileString`, with the idea that compiling the resulting string would reproduce the particular structure, so as a form of serialization.

Comment: Actually in this case using `getClass.getSimpleName`  is more appropriate because `productPrefix` can be overriden and you would then get an expression that references a nonexisting class.